# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

### EDIT

Unfortunately, this project isn't using any dependency management such as Maven or Gradle, so I have to deal with a bunch of unversioned jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder

---

I recently replaced various spring jar files in my webapp's WEB-INF/lib folder to upgrade from some old version (unknown which one) to the latest (4.2.5) in an attempt to solve a connection leak in Hibernate (using 5.0).

I'm told that Hibernate was updated some time ago, but Spring was not, and this may be the reason for our problems... so after dropping new jars (and first making sure that the code still compiles in my workspace) tomcat can't start the context because of the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at net.company.app.core.servlet.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:31)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 46 more
```

This doesn't make any sense to me though, because `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` is in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder as well.

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: You are starting the tomcat from Eclipse, right?

Answer (score 0):

When i upgraded older spring jars to latest one... i had similar (app context or some class wasnt getting loaded) while deploying app on my local server.

ensure you have no mix of old and new jars which caused problem for me. look at resolved dependencies (if using maven).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced recently many issues when migrating to newer or latest spring and hibernate. The error is self explanatory so I advice you go in direction of which jar is loading at runtime.

- For Maven project you can check the dependencies in POM.xml.
- I had the same kind of issues where conflict between older jars and new jars 
  happened. At run time it's loading the unwanted jar or older one,so best way to  remove the conflicting or older jars.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, this project isn't using any dependency management such as Maven or Gradle, so I have to deal with a bunch of unversioned jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder